# In method overloading, is method resolution takes place at compile time or run time?

Tags: java

As per my knowledge if a method is non - static and non - private, then invokevirtual instructions are added in the bytecode which results in dynamic binding at runtime, but in the following program why the compile time binding is being done.

```
class Fruit{

}

class Apple extends Fruit{

}

class MyTest{
  public void show(Fruit f){
    System.out.println("fruit");
  }

  public void show(Apple a){
    System.out.println("apple");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyTest t = new MyTest();

    Fruit f = new Fruit();
    t.show(f);

    Apple a = new Apple();
    t.show(a);

    Fruit f1 = new Apple();
    t.show(f1);
  }
}
```

The output of the following program is

```
Fruit 
Apple 
Fruit
```

I have a doubt in this following line of code

```
Fruit f1 = new Apple(); 
t.show(f1);
```

because show() is an instance method which results in invokevirtual and in case of invokevirtual, the late binding is done based on the type of object, so accordingly it should print "Apple", then why the result is "Fruit" which is based on type of reference.

Please correct me where I am wrong and what knowledge I am lacking for dynamic and compile time binding or any misconception I have related to this concept.

Comment: Resolving overloads in method calls takes place at compile time.

Comment: but here all are instance methods, which results in invokevirtual instruction which thus results in dynamic binding at runtime, so how things are getting done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does *both*, depending on the situation.

Specifically, it does the 'late binding' **only on the receiver**, **not on the parameters**.

So, given:

```
   class Fruit {
       void show(Fruit other) {
           System.out.println("I am fruit, and that is also Fruit");
       }
       void show(Apple other) {
           System.out.println("I am fruit, and that is Apple");
       }
   }
   class Apple extends Fruit {
       void show(Fruit other) {
           System.out.println("I am Apple, and that is Fruit");
       }
       void show(Apple other) {
           System.out.println("I am Apple, and that is also Apple");
       }
   }
   Fruit x = new Apple();
   Fruit y = new Apple();
   x.show(y);
```

Then `show(Fruit)` is called and not `show(Apple)` because **no late binding is applied to parameter types**. However, if the Apple class has its own `show(Fruit)` method (this is then called: It overrides the `show(Fruit)` method from Fruit), that *will* late bind, so Apple's impl of `show` is chosen and not `Fruit`'s impl.

Thus, the above prints: "I am Apple, and that is Fruit".

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation and your effort...Can u please clear that in my program whether compile time binding or runtime binding is happening at "MyTest t = new MyTest();" ? –

Comment: Constructs statically bind, but in general, `X x = new X();` means the question is moot. Late binding in any phase is not going to change what that means, it's all X.

Answer (score 5):

It **is** a virtual method call, but the virtual method is owned by `MyTest`, not by `Fruit`. The overriding would have to take place in the owner of the method, not in a class that is being passed as an explicit argument to the method.

Overriding uses the runtime type of the **owner** of the method being called; whereas resolving overloads (based on the explicit arguments to the method) takes place at compile time, so it depends on the declared compile-time type of the arguments.

If you added a `show()` method to `Fruit`, you could override it in `Apple` and it would be the `Apple` one that was called.

E.g.

```
Fruit f = new Apple();
f.show(); // calls Apple.show, if it exists
```

Comment: how "resolving overloads (based on the explicit arguments to the method) takes place at compile time" as per your statement because if methods are virtual(non - static or non - private), then the dynamic binding should take place as it will result in invokevirtual and therefore method resolution should take place at runtime(dynamic binding) based on the type of object and not at compile time...

Comment: There's compile-time resolution, followed by runtime resolution. The overloads are resolved to a declared virtual method in the receiving type by the compiler. Then at runtime, that virtual method is resolved to an actual implementation.

Comment: So, is it valid to say method overloading is done at compile time by the compiler based on reference type because at the end it is followed by the runtime resolution because at compile time it only checks whether the method exists in the provided class or not and when it receives confirmation of it's presence then only it proceeds with the runtime resolution...

Comment: Yes. The compiler has to resolve overloads to know at least whether a method call is legal (otherwise it will issue a compile error). Overrides have to be resolved at runtime because they depend on the runtime type of the receiving object.

Comment: According to you, then the compiler has to validate the method call in case of overriding too... eg: Fruit x = new Apple();
x.show(10); to check whether the show method exists in Fruit class or not and the same thing is being done in case of overloading Fruit x = new Fruit(); x.show(10);...... and then both are getting resolved at runtime only so technically resolving overloads in method call is also done at runtime only.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to convey with that example. The compiler only needs to check the compile-time type of the receiver to see if a method call is legal. Whether or not that method is overridden in a subclass does not affect whether it is a legal call.